# Generators are unable to concat with bytes in Python

Tags: python, flask, generator

I have an class that gets frames from a camera using a `get_frame` method. In a web context, I need to add some data around each frame before streaming it to the browser. When I try to add the extra information (some `bytes`) to the frame, I get `TypeError: can't concat bytes to generator`. How do I concatenate this data?

```
def gen():
    camera = VideoCamera()
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame() 
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

class VideoCamera():
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    def get_frame(self):        
        while(True):
            ret, frame = self.video.read()
            #that face is the list, which has all the detected faces in the frame, using dlib library
            face = detector(gray, 0)
            for (J, rect) in enumerate(face):
                 ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                 yield jpeg.tobytes()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, calling `get_frame` returns a generator, not an individual frame. You need to iterate over that generator to get individual frames, which you can then yield along with the other data.

```
def gen():
    camera = VideoCamera()
    for frame in camera.get_frame():
        yield b'--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'
        yield frame
        yield b'\r\n\r\n'
```